# How to solve "OS Error: File exists, errno = 17" in flutter?

Tags: flutter, download

I'm trying to download and save a file in the Downlaod directory, but every time I get this error:

```
I/flutter (21400): FileSystemException: Cannot create file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/contratto.jpg' (OS Error: File exists, errno = 17)
```

But if I search this file in my storage I don't find it, I don't understand.

In the Manifest I've all the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I'm using ext_storage package to find the path, but even with path_provider I got the same error.
This is my code:

```
static Future download(String url, String fileName, String extension) async {
    _checkPermission();
    String _localPath = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    Dio dio = Dio();
    await dio.download(
      url,
      _localPath + "/" + fileName + "." + extension,
    );
}
```

I'm using Flutter 2.0.6.
Any ideas?

EDIT:
The download works only the first time I save a file with a certain name, if I delete it and try to download it again I get this error. I've tried also to reinstall the app but I still get the error

Answer (score 7):

Apparently seems to be a problem with the way Android deletes files: the first time it works, but the next times the error compare, even if I delete manually the file.

My Solution: append a random string to file's name. I know that it's not so elegant, but it works.

```
 String filePath =
        _localPath + "/" + fileName + Uuid().v4() + "." + extension;
```

Comment: It worked, but do you know any more information about this error? what's the cause of it for example.

Comment: I don't know for sure, the error appears the second time you try to save a file with the same name (the first time you don't get the error), even if you delete the file. My theory is that there is a sort of cache or something that cause the problem.

Comment: Yes, that's what happens. very weird. Thanks anyways.

Comment: This answer did not provide solution in my case. I am checking if file exists then I opens the file using `open_file` plugin. In my case `File.exist(file)` returns false but `dio.download` showing this same error: `OS Error: File exists, errno = 17`

Comment: I am also checking the file size from `Dio().head(fileUrl)` and checking this value with the Local file. If somehow download stopped in middle and file did not delete automatically this above condition will delete the corrupted file and download again. As I am getting `File.exist(file)` as false, I can't compare the size and I have to download the file. which as mentioned throws error `OS Error: File exists, Errno = 17`

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution: Since Android 11, API level 30, there is a new storage protection. You need to request the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE access.

Solution

**Add to AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**And request Permission to manage external Storage (example with permission_handler)**

```
await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE may is not be a good idea .

You should request the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission only when your app cannot effectively make use of the more privacy-friendly APIs, such as Storage Access Framework or the Media Store API. Additionally, the app's usage of the permission must fall within permitted uses, and must be directly tied to the core functionality of the app. If your app includes a use case that's similar to the following examples, it's likely to be allowed to request the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission:

```
File managers
Backup and restore apps
Anti-virus apps
Document management apps
On-device file search
Disk and file encryption
Device-to-device data migration
```

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files