# Flutter OS Error: File exists, errno = 17

Tags: flutter, file, exists

MY ERROR -

> **Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/Music/a.png' (OS Error: File exists,
> errno = 17)**

- 

### First I create an image file and if I delete this file from the file manager application I get an error like this.

- 

### I also get this error if I want to delete the file programmatically.

- 

> FileSystemException: Cannot delete file, path =
> '/storage/emulated/0/Download/Music/a.png'
> (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

MY CODE EXAMPLE

```
Future<String> getImg(imgUrl, path2, name) async {

  File fileimg = new File(join(path2, name + '.png'));
  if (fileimg.existsSync()) fileimg.deleteSync();
  var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(imgUrl));
  fileimg.writeAsBytesSync(response.bodyBytes);
  return fileimg.path;
}
```

- 

### Actually there is no file but there is

Comment: try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67583812/how-to-solve-os-error-file-exists-errno-17-in-flutter

Comment: @Linux Hack Team Did you find any solutions?

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet